# require js on build file combine

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I use require js in my single page app and I am wondering if it is possible to combine all modules, vendor libraries (jQuery, Underscore, Backbone) in one single file, since this would speed up my app.

```
app
  css
  html
    homepage
       main.html
       login.html
       signup.html
  js
    build.js
    libs
        jquery.js
        backbone.js
        underscore.js
        require.js
    modules
       collections
       models
       views
       main
          main.js
          app.js
          router.js
app-build
```

My build configuration file currently is:

```
({
    appDir: '../',
    baseUrl: 'js/modules',
    mainConfigFile: 'modules/main/main.js',
    dir: '../../app-build',
    optimize: 'uglify',
    uglify: {
        toplevel: true,
        ascii_only: true,
        beautify: true,
        max_line_length: 1000
    },
    preserveLicenseComments: true,
    logLevel: 0
})
```

Comment: Search for combine in http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html . Is this what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm certainly not an expert in this area, but I did manage to get this working for one of my projects, admittedly mainly by trial and error.

I found that I needed to make either/both of `appdir` and `baseUrl` be a directory which contained both my code and the library code - in your case, this would either be `./app/js` or `./app` (depending on whether you also wanted your templates combined).

I also supplied paths to the various library functions.

Having got it working I really ought to go back and see what was actually necessary, and what was cargo-cult coding. For now I have more pressing code to be writing...

For your interest I include my options: note I am optimizing from node.js via `rjs.optimize(...)`.

```
var options = {
  baseUrl: "./site/app",
  appdir: "./site/app",
  name: "js/main",
  out: "main-built.js",
  paths: {
    jQuery: 'js/libs/jquery/jquery',
    Underscore: 'js/libs/underscore/underscore',
    Backbone: 'js/libs/backbone/backbone',
    Handlebars: 'js/libs/handlebars/handlebars',
    templates: 'templates'
  }
};
```

I'm not expecting this to be the correct answer, but hopefully it will lead you somewhere useful.